# Проверка присутствия реализации во время компиляции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Является ли подобная проверка на присутствие реализации функции корректной или это `ill-formed`?

```
#include <iostream>


template<bool foo_supported>
struct X {
    int foo() {
        if constexpr (foo_supported) {
            std::cout << "OK\n";
            return 42;
        } else {
            static_assert(foo_supported);
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    X<true> x;
    x.foo();

    X<false> y;
//    y.foo(); // uncomment for CT error
}
```

Можно ли написать ещё короче?

```
#include <iostream>


template<bool foo_supported>
struct X {
    int foo() {
        static_assert(foo_supported);

        std::cout << "OK\n";
        return 42;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    X<true> x;
    x.foo();

    X<false> y;
//    y.foo(); // uncomment for CT error
}
```

Comment: *"проверка на присутствие реализации функции"* - у вас в коде ничего подобного нет. Есть только лишний ассерт, срабатывающий когда `foo_supported` `false`.

Comment: @user7860670 ну так это и есть условие присутствия реализации

Comment: Ну можно написать только реализацию `X<true>`, если вариант с `false` не нужен. Тут же просто проверяется значение параметра шаблона, а не присутствие реализации каких-то функций.

Comment: @user7860670 как можно не писать определение функции при параметре `false`? Вижу вариант только с 2 специализациями класса, что добавит кучу дублирующегося кода

Comment: Если цель - запретить только конкретно этот метод, когда параметр шаблона      false, то второй вариант будет лучше. Имеет смысл добавить в `static_assert` сообщение с пояснением.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, понял

Comment: @user7860670 а формально 1 вариант соответствует стандарту? ведь там вроде как разные возвращаемые типы у функции

Comment: Это в смысле что в блоке else отсутствует return? Но так он никогда не будет выполнен.